# Why DTM Data Element is being called twice?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, adobe, adobe-analytics

I have a data element using a custom script with a default value of "_Not_Set_". The code in the data element is:

```
var elemNavValue = _satellite.readCookie('navElemName');
console.log("spot 1 - cookie value is " + elemNavValue);
if ((elemNavValue !== '')&&(elemNavValue !== undefined)&&(elemNavValue !== '_Not_Set_')){
    console.log("spot 2 - cookie value is " + elemNavValue);
    _satellite.setCookie('navElemName','_Not_Set_',1);
    return elemNavValue;
}else{
    console.log("spot 3 - cookie value is " + elemNavValue);
    _satellite.setCookie("navElemName",'_Not_Set_',1);
    return '_Not_Set_';
}
```

When the page loads, I see the data element runs twice. I get the following output in the console.

```
spot 1 - cookie value is undefined 
spot 3 - cookie value is undefined
spot 1 - cookie value is _Not_Set_ 
spot 3 - cookie value is _Not_Set_
```

This is the only data element I have declared and it is only called in the global section for Adobe Analytics tool and assigned to a prop and eVar. I have no rules created. Why is this and how do I fix this issue?

Comment: Where is the data element getting used/called?

Comment: I'm testing it. It is the only data element and it is being called in the global settings for Adobe Analytics in to a prop and evar. I don't have any rules set-up yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of being created once on page load,  Data elements run each time they are called. So, if you are using them in a prop and evar,it will be called twice. If you run

```
_satellite.getVar('data element name')
```

in the browser console, you would see the code run again. 
To stop this behavior, copy the evAR into the prop or vice versa.

Comment: So are you saying if in the global variable section of the Adobe Analytics tool, if I have eVar 1 set to the value of the data element and prop1 set to the value of the data element on page load. It runs the data element twice? Interesting, I had no idea but makes sense. I'll try your recommended fix. thanks!